# Magento - Checking if a module is installed?

Tags: magento-1.9, module

How can i check the module installed or not in magento and also the module are enabled or disbled.

Comment: Check System->Configuration->Advanced there you can check it's enable or not

Answer (score 6):

To check it programmatically, you can use the following code:

**Check if a module exists and is enabled or not in global config**

```
Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('YourCompanyName_YourModuleName');
```

**To check if your module is disabled or not from Magento backend/admin, i.e. from *System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Advanced***

```
Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('YourCompanyName_YourModuleName');
```

> The above functions are present in class **Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract**
>   (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

1. Go to `System > Configuration > Advance (bottom left)`
2. Then check your module name there and see if that is enabled or disabled

For Connect extensions, go to

```
System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager
```

[More reading](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10128/how-to-check-all-installed-in-magento-extensions#answer-10129)

Comment: Thanks, how can i install new module?

Comment: That's another question, you should create new one. Quick link is: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_connect.htm but there is another way of installing module.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this has helped you. So that future reader will get benefit.

Comment: If there any other option has install new module except magento connect manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
$moduleName = 'Mage_Core'; // edit to your required module name
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled($moduleName)) {
    echo "Module is enabled.";
} else {
    echo "Module is disabled.";
}
```